# Cannot understand why EC2 instance is not getting created whereas everything else such as VPC, route tables, security groups were created just fine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've been trying to run the below code which I copied off a YouTube tutorial I was following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLB_c_ayRMo). My EC2 instance just isn't getting created and I also checked the AWS console which doesn't show anything. Everything else appears fine as a I mentioned the VPC, subnet, route table, Internet gateway all got created as expected.

Here is the code I tried to run on windows Powershell:

```
# Create Ubuntu server and install/enable apache2

    resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance" {
    ami               = "ami-0aa2b7722dc1b5612"
    instance_type     = "t2.micro"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1"
    key_name          = "main-keyy"
```

---

I am given the below by terraform once I hit terraform apply:

```
  [0m[1maws_vpc.prod-vpc: Creating...[0m[0m
  [0m[1maws_vpc.prod-vpc: Creation complete after 4s [id=vpc- 
   0251a4f1198589dd5][0m
   [0m[1maws_internet_gateway.gw: Creating...[0m[0m
   [0m[1maws_subnet.subnet-1: Creating...[0m[0m
   [0m[1maws_security_group.allow_web: Creating...[0m[0m
    [0m[1maws_internet_gateway.gw: Creation complete after 1s 
    [id=igw- 
    007efae68da4918e7
   [0m[1maws_route_table.prod-route-table: Creating...[0m[0m
   [0m[1maws_subnet.subnet-1: Creation complete after 1s 
    [id=subnet- 
    0e7c23002f90b4999]
   [0m[1maws_route_table.prod-route-table: Creation complete after 
    2s 
    [id=rtb-0589f802
   [0m[1maws_route_table_association.a: Creating...[0m[0m
   [0m[1maws_security_group.allow_web: Creation complete after 3s 
    [id=sg-0efcc1842043c
   [0m[1maws_network_interface.web-server-nic: Creating...[0m[0m
   [0m[1maws_route_table_association.a: Creation complete after 0s 
    [id=rtbassoc-08dd47
   [0m[1maws_network_interface.web-server-nic: Creation complete 
    after 
    1s [id=eni-0e04
   [0m[1maws_eip.one: Creating...[0m[0m
   **[0m[1maws_instance.web-server-instance: Creating...[0m[0m**
   [0m[1maws_eip.one: Creation complete after 2s [id=eipalloc- 
    0df345ad18a3bbbd6][0m
```

As you can see from the above output after I hit terraform apply it doesn't create the EC2 instance neither am I given a message on the terminal to say it was a success. I cannot find the EC2 instance on the AWS console either and I've checked the AZ too. I just can't tell why this is the case.

Terraform Plan for EC2 instance:

```
  [1m  # aws_instance.web-server-instance[0m will be created
  [0m  [32m+[0m[0m resource "aws_instance" "web-server-instance" {
 [32m+[0m[0m ami                                  = "ami- 
  0aa2b7722dc1b5612"
 [32m+[0m[0m arn                                  = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m associate_public_ip_address          = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m availability_zone                    = "us-east-1"
 [32m+[0m[0m cpu_core_count                       = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m cpu_threads_per_core                 = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m disable_api_stop                     = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m disable_api_termination              = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m ebs_optimized                        = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m get_password_data                    = false
 [32m+[0m[0m host_id                              = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m host_resource_group_arn              = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m iam_instance_profile                 = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m id                                   = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m instance_state                       = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m instance_type                        = "t2.micro"
 [32m+[0m[0m ipv6_address_count                   = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m ipv6_addresses                       = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m key_name                             = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m monitoring                           = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m outpost_arn                          = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m password_data                        = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m placement_group                      = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m placement_partition_number           = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m primary_network_interface_id         = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m private_dns                          = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m private_ip                           = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m public_dns                           = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m public_ip                            = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m secondary_private_ips                = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m security_groups                      = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m subnet_id                            = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m tags                                 = {
     [32m+[0m[0m "Name" = "web-server"
   }
 [32m+[0m[0m tags_all                             = {
     [32m+[0m[0m "Name" = "web-server"
   }
 [32m+[0m[0m tenancy                              = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m user_data                            = 
  "919a5df8f376fdfd21155dfe9ce72bdddfd69512"
 [32m+[0m[0m user_data_base64                     = (known after 
  apply)
 [32m+[0m[0m user_data_replace_on_change          = false
 [32m+[0m[0m vpc_security_group_ids               = (known after 
  apply)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the `terraform plan` output. But it also sounds like maybe the `aws_instance` resource is in a file in a separate folder or subfolder from the rest of your terraform code?

Comment: Hi, I've added the terraform plan code in my original post for the EC2 instance im having issues with. all of the terraform code resides in a main.tf file I created a directory on my local machine so i'm not sure which other folders or files the instance could be in.

Comment: I don't understand why your terraform output is such an unreadable mess, but it does clearly say it is creating the instance `aws_instance.web-server-instance: Creating...` If you don't see the EC2 instance in the console, try viewing all instances, not just running instances. It could be that the instance is crashing for some reason after Terraform creates it. You will have to check that soon after you run `terraform apply` as a terminated instance only stays in the console view for a limited time.